# Formula to get the value in the cell(i,j)?

Tags: google-sheets

How to get the value in the cell(i,j) of a sheet named 'Sheet X' in Google Spreadsheets? (line i, column j)

Comment: Same document !

Comment: This needs some more information to be answerable, I think.  Why is the traditional `=A1` style not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

If `i` happens to be `1` and `j` happens to be `10` then:

```
='Sheet X'!J1
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to name the cells with their column and line numbers. Or is there a way to concatenate the "'Sheet X'!J1" ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en) and `&`:

Assuming that A1 cell content is `J`and A2 cell content is `1`

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet X!"&A1&A2)
```